# A tool to keep links towards pdf pages

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, mind-mapping, microsoft-onenote

For my researches, I review hundreds of pdf documents and I comment them while I keep some notes in Onenotes or Mindjet.

I would like a way to keep links toward specific pdf pages within my notes (the file:/// etc .pdf trick doesn't work for local files) without having to copy/clone my pdf to a specific directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Named destinations](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/choose_your_destination/) seems to be what you're looking for.

You can create them in Adobe Acrobat, and link to the PDF either using `file://` or set up an HTTP server for the root directory for your PDFs, and use `http://` to link to specific sections of the PDF.

[Here's the link](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G11.1947713) to the Named Destination section of the PDF spec.